# Editing Access forms while other people are using

Tags: ms-access

Is there any workaround people are aware of to edit Access forms while the database is in use by someone else on the network?

Solved(?): Think I figured this out. I guess I didn't fully understand how a split database worked yet. I'm going to split the database, hide the backend in my own folder. The front end will be on the share drive for anyone to use. I can make as many copies of the front end as I want, as they'll all be linked to the tables in the backend location. I can edit the structure of the front end whenver I want and just replace the one in the share drive for people to access.

Comment: Depends. Are you using split architecture? Do you have `RecordLocks` set?

Comment: The database isn't split right now but I definitely can do so. I'm unsure what RecordLocks is

Comment: RecordLocks is a form property that tells Access to lock/don't lock/only lock records when a Form is open or someone is editing records. Setting `No Locks` allows two users to simultaneously make changes -- proceed with caution, knowing the autonomy you're granting the users.

Comment: Here's a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197407.aspx) for RecordLocks

Comment: Can I delete the linked tables from the Front end database? I think I read somewhere that if you delete them from the front end, the data is still updated in the backend file's tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to create a split end database.  That way you can work on your copy while others are still able to use the database.  You can find information about it in the following link: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Split-an-Access-database-3015ad18-a3a1-4e9c-a7f3-51b1d73498cc

If you already have a split database than simply just work on your own master copy and send out the updated version to whomever will be using it.

Comment: Thank you! With the split end database, though, can I edit actual forms while other users are using those forms? In other words, is there any way for me to edit a form while a user is simultaneously entering data into it so that the form will update for them the next time they open the database?

Comment: You should throw in the bit about record locks

Comment: I don;t think RecordLocks would suit us because we use Access for the purpose of allowing two users to make edits at the same time. Does RecordLock lock only that one particular row in a table or the entire form/table?

Comment: I was mentioning it to Newd, sorry.

Comment: @Invent-Animate In all honesty haven't had enough personal experience to feel like I should pass it on, just kind of one of those things that have always worked fine with even 25 people using the database.  Does the record locking change from a joint database to a split end database?